# Filtering not working via search bar in Django and react

Tags: reactjs, django, api, django-rest-framework, filtering

I want to filter products based on their title. I defined a `get_queryset` method in `ProductViewSet` for filtering. But it is not able to read the text which is being searched.

views.py

```js
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    pagination_class = DefaultPagination
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set = Product.objects.all()
        txt = self.request.query_params.get('search')
        if txt is not None:
            query_set = query_set.filter(title__icontains=txt)
        return query_set

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(self.get_queryset(), many=True, context={'cart_id': 0})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Navigation.jsx

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContext } from '../App';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Navigation() {

  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  const [searchtxt, setSearchTxt] = useState();

  const handler = async() => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`products/?search=${searchtxt}`);
    console.log(data);
  }

  return (
    <div>
       <div className='navbar'>
        <div id='logo'>
          Shopy
        </div>
        <form className='search-section' onSubmit={handler}>
          <input required name='search' type='text' onChange={(e) => setSearchTxt(e.target.value)} />
          <button type='submit'>search</button>
        </form>
        <div className='info-section'>
          {user?<p>Hi, {user.username} <Link to='/logout'>Logout</Link></p>:<p><Link to='/login'>Login</Link></p>}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The if condition inside `get_queryset` is always false. I dont know why the txt is None or why `self.request.query_params` is not working.